# Updating foreign key from different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

```
Admin
id    email
1     test@test.com
2     abc@test.com

Users
id    email
331   test@test.com
931   abc@test.com

Code
id    owner_id (Foreign Key)
2     1
```

I want to delete the Admin table and update the Code table to change the owner_id to be the ID from Users.

So for this example:

```
Code
id    owner_id
2     331
```

Can the update be done with one single SQL query?